# Python Find object in a list of objects

Tags: python

I have a list of objects and I want to find a specific object.

I have a text file with data about how hungry pets are and where they are:

```
The cat,5,at the door
The dog,1,at the bed
The bunny,4,at the car
```

My code looks like this:

```
class Pets:
    
    def __init__(self, pet, hunger, where):
        self.pet=pet
        self.hunger=hunger
        self.where=where
   

def main():
    data=readFile()
    allPets=makeObjects(data)
    howHungry(allPets)

def readFile():
   with open('data.txt') as cvsfile:
       reader = csv.reader(cvsfile)
       i=0
       data = []

       for row in reader:           
           i+=1
           print(row)
           data.append(row)
   return (data)


def makeObjects(data):
    allPets=[]
    i=0
    while i < len(data):
        allPets.append(Pets(data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2]))
        i += 1
           
    return allPets



def howHungry(allPets):
```

Everything works until I get to the howHungry function. I want to print how hungry the dog is. How do I find where the dog is in the list of objects?
I have tried to use index, but that does only work with lists.

Comment: `[animal.hunger for animal in allPets if animal.pet = "dog"]` This will return huner of all animals that are called "dog" from the list of all pets.

Comment: @matszwecja I agree, only a slight correction:
`[animal.hunger for animal in allPets if "dog" in animal.pet][0]`

Comment: I think `==` is better than `in` in that case (yeah I know I wrote `=`, that sure is a mistake). Let's say you want to find a horse, `in` will also match a with pet named "seahorse".

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a list containing `Pets` object instances, you indeed can't use `.index()` directly; instead, you'll need a loop of some sort; here it's just a plain old `for` loop.

```
def print_hungry_doggos(all_pets):
    for pet in all_pets:  # loop over all pets
         if "dog" in pet.pet:  # if the name contains dog, assume it's a dog
              print(f"{pet.pet}'s hunger level is {pet.hunger}")
```

As an aside:

- class names should be singular, in general
- function and variable names are typically `snake_case`, not `camelCase`, in Python.
- `while` loops are generally quite rare in Python.

Your code is more idiomatic (without using e.g. list comprehensions) as

```
import csv


class Pet:
    def __init__(self, pet, hunger, where):
        self.pet = pet
        self.hunger = hunger
        self.where = where

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.pet} is {self.hunger} in {self.where}"


def read_file():
    with open('data.txt') as cvsfile:
        return list(csv.reader(cvsfile))  # iterates over the CSV reader to generate a single list of lists


def make_objects(csv_data):
    pets = []
    for row in csv_data:
        pets.append(Pet(pet=row[0], hunger=row[1], where=row[2]))
    return pets


def main():
    csv_data = read_file()
    all_pets = make_objects(csv_data)
    for pet in all_pets:
        print(pet)
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and the help! Maybe I am thinking wrong, but I want to be able to update the hunger of a pet. Because I can't find the index like in a normal list, it would be hard to update the object in a list. Should I update the data in the csv_data and then run make_objects again?

Comment: No – now that you've "hydrated" data from the CSV file into memory, you can edit the object however you like. E.g. `for pet in all_pets: pet.hunger *= 10` would make all pets 10x as hungry.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overriding the *eq* dunder function. Here's an example:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, animal, hunger, location):
        self.animal = animal
        self.hunger = hunger
        self.location = location
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return other == self.animal
        if isinstance(other, Animal):
            other.animal == self.animal
        return False

animal_1 = Animal('dog', 5, 'In the garden')
animal_2 = Animal('cat', 2, 'In the bedroom')

lst = [animal_1, animal_2]

for animal in ['dog', 'cat', 'monkey']:
    try:
        i = lst.index(animal)
        print(f'The {animal} is {lst[i].location}')
    except ValueError:
        print(f'Couldn\'t find the {animal}')
```

**Output:**

```
The dog is In the garden
The cat is In the bedroom
Couldn't find the monkey
```